# Is there something special about the variables that are passed via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I am trying to access a database and delete a review of a user, I have a method that I pass the user's ID and the ID of the review. This method functions properly using both the SQL command as well as when I call hard-coded variables, however, when I pass the code via AJAX my code says it completed successfully but does not actually do anything. Is there something special about the variables that are passed via AJAX?

This is my method:

```
 public function deleteRating($userid, $reviewID)
    {
        echo "this is idUsers(IdUsers) = ".$userid." this is reviewID (ID)".$reviewID;
        $conn = $this->connect("ratings");
        $sql = "DELETE FROM ratedmovies WHERE IdUsers=? AND ID=?";

        if(!$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))
        {
            echo "False";
        }
        else
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userid, $reviewId);
            if(!$stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "Failed to delete";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Sucessfull Deletion";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that calls the method:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include "../Model/Includes/autoLoadCont.inc.php";
   $reviews = new Review;
   $ratingID = json_decode($_POST['ratingID']);
   $user = $_SESSION['userId'];
   $reviews->deleteRating($user, $ratingID);
?>
```

and this is the ajax that calls that function:

```
var deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteRating");
deleteBtns.forEach(function(button)
{
    button.addEventListener("click" , function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Controller/deleteReview.php",
            data: {ratingID:button.id},
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
    button.id;
});
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` is the first step.

Comment: This is how you troubleshoot what is in a variable?

Comment: Si senor!!!!!!!

Comment: I have done that and I got what I see as an associative array with a string with the correct value in the string. array(1) {
  ["ratingID"]=>
  string(1) "8"
} this should be good and it logs correctly when I call the variable, any idea what issue may be showing up here?

Comment: Side note: you don't need to decode here: `$ratingID = json_decode($_POST['ratingID'])` as you're not sending the params as JSON.

Comment: Thanks so much, el_vanja, I did change that, sadly it had no effect on the variables passing through... : (

Comment: I have tried everything I could think of. my datatype on my SQL server was int, so I tried changing the bind param to "ii", which did not work. I am connecting fine, the SQL statement works when I put it in phpMyAdmin and substitute the variables for there respective numbers. and every time I run the function the echo "Successful Deletion" is echoed, which I think means the stmt->execute() should work.  I am at a total loss here.

Comment: Check the server logs, you may have NOTICE because of a typo. At the `bind_param` you have `$reviewId`, but the others before that point are `$reviewID`.

Comment: OMG, that was it.... that was it... I thought i checked everything like that. I don't know how to check the server logs yet, I'm new to programming but I will figure that out and do that before I make a stupid spelling mistake and can't catch it.....Thanks so much.

Comment: Yeah, I get tripped up by that every once in awhile. Know that with PHP, variables (and class properties) ARE case sensitive, but class names and function names are NOT. Know that it's helpful to tail the server log in a console `tail -F /path/to/server/error_log` while developing, as you'll catch things like that sooner.

Comment: Also, the tips provided by others is good debug info too. Using those tips can be used to check that the information is at least being passed through AJAX as expected. Also, don't forget about the browser's built-in web inspector console tab to look for potential javascript-related error(s) or other situations. You can even set breakpoints and step through the javascript code too, and the network tab there can even help check the AJAX requests and responses as well.